# Discord(JS) bot not detecting presenceUpdate

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, user-presence

In Discord.js (v.12.4.1), anytime a user changes their presence (e.g. status, activity), presenceUpdate should be fired; however, the bot is not detecting any updates. I have tried changing status states, changing custom status, listening to Spotify or playing a game that has rich presence, but none of the above triggers the event. Other events such as `bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', ...)` has no problem. Is there anything wrong with this code? Thanks.

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.login(TOKEN);

...

bot.on('presenceUpdate', (oldP, newP) => {
  // do things, for example
  console.log(newP);
});
```